# What can cause banding textures in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, textures, rendering, deferred, visual-glitch

I recently rewrote the lighting engine in a project I've been working on and noticed that I am getting banding on textures, and only in one direction per face.

The lighting engine is now deferred rendering, so it is composed of 3 textures processed as scene data. Could this be the cause of the texture banding?

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Banding texture]

It only seems to occur where the lighting is close.

If it helps, my 3 textures are in the following formats:

```
World fragment position: GL_RGBA16F - GL_FLOAT
World normal direction: GL_RGBA16F - GL_FLOAT
Fragment diffuse texture: GL_RGBA - GL_UNSIGNED_INT
```

Comment: I think they may be rounding errors from the angle in which the light hits the surface (leading to a low dot product between normal and direction)

Comment: Thanks! That did it, all I changed was GL_RGBA16F to GL_RGBA32F.

Comment: `GL_RGBA` is not a very descriptive internal format, by the way. You should use `GL_RGBA8` since you are using a sized format for the floating-point buffers.

Comment: I guess more memory isn't too big of a problem and makes a lot of aesthetic difference. If you post you comment as an answer I'll accept it for you

Comment: Oh and good point @AndonM.Coleman
Do you know what it defaults to in the case of ambiguity?

Comment: Nobody does, that is why I suggested you pick an explict size =P It is up to the implementation what the internal format defaults to when you do not specify anything, though on desktop GL `GL_RGBA8` is probably going to be the internal format most of the time - GL does not require this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to ratchet freak and Andon M. Coleman.

Ratchet freak pointed out that it was probably a rounding error in the angle at which the light hits the surface (leading to a low dot product between normal and direction).

The cause was that the internal format of the normal direction texture was set to GL_RGBA16F - 16 bit floats which caused the rounding. Setting the format to GL_RGBA32F fixed the rounding by holding 32 bit floats.

Andon M. Coleman pointed out that I should stop using GL_RGBA as an internal format because it is ambiguous and that GL_RGBA8 was appropriate